# Image Sprites in Single Image VB.Net App

Tags: css, vb.net

How can I use image sprites in single image using vb.net just like the css feature in web app.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do ? You can easily put an image sprite and use that sprite using CSS at the required place.